# Create regex pattern for below string

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone please suggest me how we can create pattern for below string.

```
String stringToFind = "Abcdef_ghi_2.0-123_20150424_1642_text.tar.gz";
```

I have tried with given pattern, but no use. Felt that some where its not satisfying with pattern.

```
String pattern = "Abcdef_ghi_*_(\\d{8})_(\\d{4})_\\w+";
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Read a regex tutorial. `*` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: `String pattern = "Abcdef_ghi_[\\d.-]+_(\\d{8})_(\\d{4})_[.\\w]+";`

Comment: You should tell us 1st what's the fixed part and what's the dynamic part expected

Comment: Here i want to get 20150424 and 1642 from stringToFind variable. That's my requirement.Which I got it from below answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `_*` you need to use `_.*?`.

You can use:

```
String pattern = "Abcdef_ghi_.*?_(\\d{8})_(\\d{4})_\\w+.*";
```

Comment: Anubhava, You have to keep \\d instead of \d.Even after correcting this , its not working.Thanks for your reply

Comment: How are you matching? Are you calling `String#matches()` method?

Comment: Also I didn't use `\d` anywhere I have kept it as `\\d`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
 String pattern = "Abcdef_ghi_.*(\\d{8})_(\\d{4})_\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*";
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [19-27] `20150424`
2.  [28-32] `1642`
```

Comment: stribizhew, its worked as expected.Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: You are welcome. You should also be more specific, I felt you were using `matches` method, that is why I extended the pattern till the end. I'd recommend using `matcher.find()`, but it is really up to you.

Comment: @Honey, please accept this answer since it answered your question